# nursery application - how to structure my database

Tags: php, database, cakephp, database-design, data-structures

I'm having trouble getting my head around exactly what is the best way to build an application which is supposed to manage a nursery, particularly, who is in what room when.

Nurseries have several rooms and each room has an age range allowed in it, and a maximum number of children it can accommodate at any one time.

Children get booked in in a rota type style for mornings and afternoons, so a kid might be booked to be in on the following times.

```
monday   am pm
tuesday     pm
wed         pm
thurs    am pm 
fri      am pm 
sat      
sun
```

So I collect this rota in a table like so:

```
id
child_id
mon_am <-- if booked in then 1, if not then 0
mon_pm 
tues_am 
etc...
```

And then allocate a child to a room.

Now when adding a new child I need to be able to check to see what rooms there are spaces available in, so that I can know whether the appropriate room has the spare capacity. So with the info above and assuming the room in question has a capacity (for example) of 1 child, if someone wants to sign up for that room on tues and wed am, then they can because the first kid isn't booked in at that time.

I'm a bit new to all this and I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do to check if a room has spare capacity. Can anyone help me out at all?

thanks

Comment: You can run a query to see if the room has space. If so, return `TRUE` and add the student to the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS `numChildrenBooked` FROM `your_table` WHERE `mon_am` = 1;
```

will return the number of rows in which mon_am is == 1 in your table. Compare that to the maximum number of children per room to check if there's space available.

What's bad in your db-structure probably is (I think) that you can only plan for one week at once...

Comment: Hi jwulf, thanks for the comment. Any advice on how to make my database structure better? At the moment I can change it but I'm really a novice at database design, I don't want to make a load of mistakes.

Comment: Well, usefull would be:
- 1 Table for children (with column id and any others, name etc.)
- 1 Table for rooms (with column id and whatever else you need)
- 1 Table for bookings with columns for child-ID, room-ID and date/time.

That way you can store and look up, which room is occupied when and also store the allocations.